# How do I remove the front panel of my refrigerator to replace the water line?

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Whirlpool Gold Conquest side by side refrigerator, Model #GS2SHEXNB00. Here's the tag:

[image: tag]

It has a line that runs through the freezer door to the water dispenser in the front. Water has started to slowly drip down the line and pool at the bottom. I am guessing there is a crack in the line somewhere inside the door, but I can't figure out how to get at it.

[image: dripping line]

I'm fairly certain that I need to remove the ice/water dispenser to get at the line:

[image: water/ice dispenser, cover removed]

I've managed to remove the faceplate and there are four screws at the corners of the dispenser, but after removing them, it still doesn't budge. I think there may be some sort of glue holding it in. I've worked a knife around the edges and loosened them up, but it's still pretty firmly in there.

How can I get that thing out of there? Or is that even the right place to replace the water line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace the water line, you need to remove the entire door - the water line from the dispenser runs through it.

The water line from the dispenser is one continuous piece through the door. By disconnecting it at the dispenser, you can pull it out the bottom of the door.

Comment: So I have to replace the entire door?

Answer (score 2):

To save you a lot of time and headache: If the water line is frozen in the door, then the door has to be replaced.  The reason being the door is completely assembled at the factory and then it is filled with foam insulation.  If the channel for the water line moved during the pour and moved back close to the door liner and that is what is causing it to freeze, then it is non-repairable.